# Why does Postgresql gives row number of answers for a count request?

Tags: postgresql, count

I am using Postgresql **9.4**.
I have this table recorded:

```
 Colonne |         Type          | Modificateurs 
---------+-----------------------+---------------
 noemp   | integer               | non NULL
 nomemp  | character varying(15) | 
 emploi  | character varying(14) | 
 mgr     | integer               | 
 dateemb | date                  | 
 sal     | real                  | 
 comm    | real                  | 
 nodept  | integer               |
```

Which has those values inside:

```
noemp |  nomemp   |     emploi     | mgr  |  dateemb   | sal  | comm | nodept 
-------+-----------+----------------+------+------------+------+------+--------
  7369 | SERGE     | FONCTIONNAIRE  | 7902 | 1980-12-07 |  800 |      |     20
  7499 | BRAHIM    | VENDEUR        | 7698 | 1981-02-20 | 1600 |  300 |     30
  7521 | NASSIMA   | VENDEUR        | 7698 | 1981-02-22 | 1250 |  500 |     30
  7566 | LUCIE     | GESTIONNAIRE   | 7839 | 1981-04-02 | 2975 |      |     20
  7654 | MARTIN    | VENDEUR        | 7698 | 1981-09-28 | 1250 | 1400 |     30
  7698 | BENJAMIN  | GESTIONNAIRE   | 7839 | 1981-05-01 | 2850 |      |     30
  7782 | DAYANE    | GESTIONNAIRE   | 7839 | 1981-06-09 | 2450 |      |     10
  7788 | ARIJ      | ANALYSTE       | 7566 | 1982-12-09 | 3000 |      |     20
  7839 | MAYAR     | PRESIDENT      |      | 1981-11-17 | 5000 |      |     10
  7844 | ROI       | VENDEUR        | 7698 | 1981-09-08 | 1500 |    0 |     30
  7876 | VIRGINIE  | FONCTIONNAIRE  | 7788 | 0983-01-12 | 1100 |      |     20
  7902 | ASMA      | ANALYSTE       | 7566 | 1981-12-03 | 3000 |      |     20
  7934 | SIMONE    | FONCTIONNAIRE  | 7782 | 1982-01-23 | 1300 |      |     10
  7900 | LYNA      | FONCTIONNAIRE  | 7698 | 1981-12-03 |  950 |      |     30
(14 lignes)
```

When I make a function to count the number of "`nodept`" with an asked value like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION depcount(integer)RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
somme integer;
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) FROM EMP WHERE nodept=$1 INTO somme ;

RETURN somme;
END$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

with a `SELECT depcount(30) FROM EMP;`
I get this answer:

```
----------
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
        6
(14 lignes)
```

14 results, as I should normally have only one.
I have to specify that I'm doing this for a course and I can't change the postgresql version, which must be 9.4.
If you have any idea why I get 14 results instead of one ?
thank you.

Comment: You are selectting from EMP table, without filtering, so you get results as rows are in that table. Just try "SELECT depcount(30);" or "SELECT depcount(30) FROM EMP LIMIT 1;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing the function once per row, running the `SELECT COUNT(*)` 14 times and getting the result once for each row.
You probably want `SELECT depcount(30)` (without a`FROM` clause), to run the function only once.

On a side note, using a function for this sort of query is a bit overkill in most case in my opinion. You also don't need to use `plpgsql`, `language sql` would be enough here  (though your function may be a bit more complicated than in your example). Using `DISTINCT(COUNT(*))` doesn't really make sense either.